# Centering flexbox content after a linebreak

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to center text inside a parent element of limited width. However the text is set in a large font, which might cause a line-break. However the element line-break does not decrease the width of the  element. Is there a way to center a text inside a parent wrapper if the text does not fit?

You can find a failing example in the stack-overflow code sample. The top box has a line-break and should still be centered.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
 
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
    background: green;
    font-size: 45px;
  }
   .box:nth-child(2) {
    background: orange;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"><h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3></div>
<div class="box"><h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `text-align: center;`

Comment: As I know, the's no way, unfortunately...

Comment: @Qwertiy do you mean scripts for reducing font-size to make possible contain the text in one line? If yes, you right, but I didn't found any notes about that in a question, so...

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, no I mean https://jsfiddle.net/Lqw2078c/ (open in Chrome). At least at point of horisontal text positioning - there is nothing about background in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `text-align: center;`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* text-align: center; */
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
 
}
.box > * {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
    background: green;
    font-size: 45px;
  }
   .box:nth-child(2) {
    background: orange;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"><h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3></div>
<div class="box"><h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Then it'll be centered as text, but he wants to center block of text.

Comment: Actually block with the text is centered by flexbox, but has word which overlapped and going to the next line. So that the issue not with the flexbox

Comment: @Qwertiy isn't OP just asking how to align text in centre of flexbox if it wraps? *Is there a way to center a text inside a parent wrapper if the text does not fit* (That seems to be the only difference between the top and bottom box)

Comment: @Qwertiy Please doublechecking answer before making down votes, okay?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, I haven't voted on this answer. Just left a comment that it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Qwertiy Okay, sorry =)

Comment: Thanks. Though as @Qwertiy wrote I need the text to stay aligned left.

Comment: @dwigt, https://jsfiddle.net/Lqw2078c/ (open in Chrome) - do I understand your question right?

Comment: @dwigt okay, just add the width for children elements to flex work like you want

Comment: @dwigt check answer now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width:min-content;` with the first child (https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.box:nth-child(1) h3 {
 width:-webkit-min-content;
 width:-moz-min-content;
 width:min-content;
 border:1px solid;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Loreme Ipsum</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```